# Google feeds schema for event indexing issue

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented Google feeds schema for event listing for the site I work on and I tested it with google.com/structured-data/testing-tool. There are no errors.

I am trying to get events picked up by Google Search with showtimes directly clickable to the event pages of the site. Some are movie screenings, some are performances. So far Google indexed the titles, days and showtimes, but none of these are clickable to the event page.

Here is a snippet of the json feed:

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
[
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Lady Bird",
  "startDate" : "2017-12-18T16:30:00",
  "location" : {"@type" : "Place","name": "BAM Rose Cinemas","address" : {"@type" : "PostalAddress","addressLocality" : "Brooklyn","addressRegion": "NY"}},"offers" : {"@type" : "Offer","url": "https://cinematickets.bam.org/#tickets/24419/6866/d39d8941-529f-4864-a871-a3a900d2b1d6","availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"}},{"@context": "http://schema.org","@type": "Event","name": "Lady Bird","startDate" : "2017-12-18T19:00:00","location" : {"@type" : "Place","name": "BAM Rose Cinemas","address" : {"@type" : "PostalAddress","addressLocality" : "Brooklyn","addressRegion": "NY"}},"offers" : {"@type" : "Offer","url": "https://cinematickets.bam.org/#tickets/24417/6866/d39d8941-529f-4864-a871-a3a900d2b1d6","availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"}
  }
]
</script>
```

There are 2 showtimes in this feed. First I tried with the URL as a property of the event top node, then I put the URL as property under offers. Pretty much same result.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the showtimes directly clickable to the event pages of the site?

Comment: This is a good question, but it's probably more on-topic on [Webmasters.StackExchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Try posting your question there for a more specialist audience.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that the `Offer` does not have a `name` that identifies the `url`. Give this a try:

```
[{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Lady Bird",
    "startDate": "2017-12-18T16:30:00",
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "BAM Rose Cinemas",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Brooklyn",
            "addressRegion": "NY"
        }
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "name": "Our price for early birds to see Lady Bird",
        "url": "https://cinematickets.bam.org/#tickets/24419/6866/d39d8941-529f-4864-a871-a3a900d2b1d6",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
    }
},
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Lady Bird",
    "startDate": "2017-12-18T19:00:00",
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "BAM Rose Cinemas",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Brooklyn",
            "addressRegion": "NY"
        }
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "name": "Our first evening show to see Lady Bird"
        "url": "https://cinematickets.bam.org/#tickets/24417/6866/d39d8941-529f-4864-a871-a3a900d2b1d6",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
    }
}]
```

An alternative approach, that will be easier to maintain, is to create a unique `<script>` for each `@Type` and then link using `@ID`. Then you could add a `description` to each `item` to give harvesters more information to re-purpose. Of course you can add `description` to your current design too. Bottom line: provide more properties for each instance of a `@Type` to guide the harvesters.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I added name and description to the offers. We'll see if Google picks it up. Also I wanted to mention something about the previous config results. The showtimes would come up but they would not be clickable. Also underneath the main result there would be a result of the days it was showing and name of the location that is clickable to one of the events of that day and it's purchase path. This was caused by mentioning the url as a property of the top event node rather than the offers. So is it critical is to have offers vs more properties at the event level ?

Comment: Also you mentioned an alternative approach, that will be easier to maintain, is to create a unique <script> for each Type and then link using ID. Could you give an example of what that would look like and how they would link? Thank you.